# Customise Slick.js

Tags: jquery, css, slider, carousel

I'm trying to add some custom buttons to the Slick.js jQuery slider, in place of the dots that the plugin uses. I'm not great with jQuery so I don't know what code I could add to sync the slider with my buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just override the `.slick-dots` CSS class in [slick.css](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.css).

```
.slick-dots li button:before {
    background: url(myButton.png);
    content: normal;
}
```

Or if you need to modify the dot content itself, do something like:

```
$('.slick-dots button').remove();
$('.slick-dots li:nth-child(1)').append('<div class="btn btn-slider">First</div>');
$('.slick-dots li:nth-child(2)').append('<div class="btn btn-slider">Second</div>');
$('.slick-dots li:nth-child(3)').append('<div class="btn btn-slider">Third</div>');
```

It seems to work, not very tested though. See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uusa5wyy/1/).

Comment: That would be perfect, sorry for not explaining very well I'm very tired. I wanted to have eg. <div class="btn btn-slider>First</div> <div class="btn btn-slider>Second</div> <div class="btn btn-slider>Third</div> as the buttons. It's not actually an image or a button element.

Comment: Almost perfect, thank you so much. That's closer than I ever got it, just need to play with the css for spacing issues. Thanks again!